# Signing pdf partially, validating partial signature

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, partial

Is it possible to partially sign pdf file programmatically and than validate each digital signature?

What I would like to do, is to give a user opportunity to generate pdf file, and than sign it. Next user can add his own text to this pdf at the end and then sign it too. I would like to have the opportunity to check every signature to see if next user didn't change previous text.

Does pdf standard provides solution for such scenario or I have write my own solution? 
If yes, maybe you know about some free libraries for C#?

Comment: Regular PDF signatures (which can be verified by e.g. adobe reader) allow only very few changes afterwards since reader version 9. Using your own verification schemes, though, you can implement more or less anything but standard viewers won't verify those schemes out of the box.

Comment: You may consider using PDF portfolios into which each of your users adds a single PDF he signs in the usual way. This way you have one PDF, the portfolio, containing many parts which can be individually signed. Something like that can be implemented using iTextSharp (open source, usage subject to AGPL); other decent PDF libraries should allow that, too.

Comment: Read http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures There's a 'workflow' example in chapter 2. "Next user can add his own text" could be problematic (but maybe a form field is sufficient). Portfolios as suggested by mkl could be a nice workaround.